# An OCR model that can be easily improved on the user side

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, svm, ocr

I am building OCR software, for this purpose I trained a model on many types of fonts, the model is `SVM` or `NN` but it is not principled.

Now I want the users of the software to be able to improve the model they received from me, when the users come across a font that the model does not recognize accurately, they will want to improve the model, how can they do this?

For this purpose, do I need to bring them the model together with all the training data, and all the pictures of the letters, and will they have to do the whole long training from the beginning for every letter that the users want to add to the model?

Or is there a way to bring users a ready-made model and on the other hand give users the option to improve the model easily?

Is there a type of model that you can add letters to without rebuilding it?

Can [Transfer Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) help here? If so, in what form?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.